# jQuery: propagating events & actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for the wrong title.

**[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jvL8z2dw/)**

**Description:**

I have 2 events attached to the same element that has different classes depending on it's state.

The first `click` event adds an `expanded` class and change it's text (for visibility purposes only).

The second `click` event is attached to the element modified by `expanded` class.

**The Problem:**

The second `click` event never fires. Doesn't remove the class and changes the text.

---

If you try it without `event.stopPropagation`it instantly fires both first & second `click` events, with first one doesn't do any visual change to the element.

> jQuery

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    $(this).text('Expanded class added');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on('click','button.expanded', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    $(this).text('Expanded class removed')
});
```

**The question:** How do I properly execute the click events with both of them doing what they are supposed to?

Comment: Need to pass `event` as param to the click handler

Comment: @Tushar ? still the same.

Comment: @Tushar both your comments are wrong. I tried immediate before I posted this. Post a working fiddle or stop spamming the comments.

Answer (score 4):

1. Bind event on `button`
2. Check if the clicked button has class `expanded`, if present remove it else add it.
3. Update the innerText of the clicked element. The ternary operator used `$(this).hasClass('expanded') ? "added" : "removed")` will return `"added"` if the button has class `expanded` added(*in second step*), otherwise returns `"removed"`.

**Code:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded') // Toggle `expanded` class of the clicked button
        .text('Expanded class ' + ($(this).hasClass('expanded') ? "added" : "removed")); // Update text
});
```

### -DEMO-

**EDIT:** for the fun, to set the text button content, you can use CSS pseudo elements:

```js
$(document).on('click','button', function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
button:not([class]):before {
  content: "Click me"
}
button.expanded:after {
  content: "added";
}
button[class]:not(.expanded):after {
  content: "removed";
}
button[class]:before {
  content: "Expanded class "
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button></button>
```

Comment: @A.Wolff Well, that's **really** optimal, clever use of CSS, you should also add that in answer

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks, really a nice one. The issue is that I got more complex logics in the real app project, so the conditional statements are more of a use.

Comment: Yes actually i am saying this is an optimal solution :-) i missed "this is"

Answer (score 3):

I think a simpler way to think about this is to put both handlers inside the delegated click event:

```
$(document).on('click','button', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('expanded')) {
        $(event.target).removeClass('expanded');
        $(event.target).text('Expanded class removed')
  }
  else {
        $(event.target).addClass('expanded');
        $(event.target).text('Expanded class added');
  }
  return false;
});
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jvL8z2dw/4/

Comment: Use `$(this).toggleClass('expanded');` outside of `if..else`

Comment: One more thing, this also binds event to all the elements which are added dynamically, in OP code, the event is bound to only elements present in the DOM at the time of event binding.

Comment: @Tushar - I purposely didn't use `toggleClass` in this example, because the if/else was needed no matter what, and keeping it like this made the structure more clear.  But it's fine either way, for sure.

Comment: @Tushar - yes, that's correct about the binding.  The OP would have to modify accordingly if needed, which should be straightforward to do.

Answer (score 0):

Made this little clean and robust.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
  if ($(this).hasClass("expanded")) {
    $(this).text('Expanded class added');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Expanded class removed')
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
.expanded {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it for you

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function (event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded')
    if($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
        $(this).text('Expanded class added');
    } else {
        $($this).text('Expanded class removed')
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Welcome! Also, add explanation with code, just code dump is not helpful.